# Getting A count of rows that match in mvc 3 using EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have a mvc 3 app that uses EF. In one function I need to get a count of rows that match a statement. I thought I could just do it like this:

```
   Dim _ClassCount As Integer = _CurrRegistrants.Where(Function(c) c.tues_class = _CurrCourse.course_ref).Count
```

But that stays at 0 even when there are 40 records that match the criteria.. I think I have the right idea I just need to change the syntax a little.. Anyone know where this is failing?

```
Dim _CurrRegistrants As List(Of reg_classes) = db.reg_classes.ToList
For Each Course In _courses.Where(Function(a) a.course_day = "Tuesday")
            Dim _CurrCourse As cours = Course
               Dim _ClassCount As Integer = _CurrRegistrants.Where(Function(c) c.tues_class = _CurrCourse.course_ref).Count
```

Comment: Did you want to assign CurrCourse.course_ref to c.tues_class or did you want to compare the two?

Comment: I am comparing the two... Where it finds matches I need to get the count..

Comment: And _CurrRegistrants is your dbContext?

Comment: Yes please look at my edit... you will see where both are defined...

Comment: Fixed it... When you asked that it made me realize I needed not use the list(of xxxx) for it... So I instead changed it to.... Dim _ClassCount as Integer = db.reg_class.Where(function(c) c.tues_class = _CurrCoutse.course_ref).Count

Comment: Thanks much for the questions... I was overlooking it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From looking at the first example of the code it appears that you might be pulling data from somewhere other than the data context. Add the data context to your query and you should then be able to access to records which you are attempting to compare each other to.